# the best easy way to show many same word using javascript

Tags: javascript, string

i want to show mant 's' , so my code is :

```
alert('s'*3)
```

but it is not running good ,

so i have to :

```
    var str='';
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
    str+='s'
    alert(str)
```

but it  is not easy ,

so did you know some more easy way to show many same word  ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice function: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#JavaScript

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(n) {
    return new Array(1 + parseInt(n, 10)).join(this);
}

alert("ha".repeat(5));  // hahahahaha
```

Comment: why are you passing a string instead of an integer?

Comment: Could do with some errorchecking: String.prototype.repeat = function(n){ n=parseInt(n,10)+1; return n ? Array(n).join(this) : this.toString(); };

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't like phpJS much, but they have [a very nice 1-line implementation](http://phpjs.org/functions/str_repeat:526) of PHP's `str_repeat()`.

If you use the function shown there, you can do a

```
alert(str_repeat('s', 3));
```

or if you don't want to copy over the function, steal its contents. This works standalone:

```
alert(new Array(4).join("s"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to make a function, that doing your long code variant?

```
function mult_str(str, count) {
   var res = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       res += str;
   }
   return res;
}
alert(mult_str('s', 3));
```